# Exporting selected feature to Google Earth in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-earth, export, select

Does anyone know if there is a plugin for QGIS that will export features to Google Earth similar to the one for MapInfo?

Answer (score 4):

Select the features, right click on the layer, "Save selection as"-> *.kml

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to export it directly to google earth. e.g so it opens and zooms to it straight away?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you need to do, but in QGIS, you can put Google Maps inside QGIS directly using the Openlayers plugin.

Comment: To be precise, in QGIS 2.14.8: select features --> right-click layer --> "save as", choose KML, choose CRS WGS84 (EPSG 4326), choose "Save only selected features", choose the wanted field for name and description within GE.

Answer (score 0):

This is also quite cool, if 'save as kml' isn't rich enough for your needs. Worth watching the video also, gives a good precis of what it does: http://gis-lab.info/qa/qgis2google-eng.html